# My soft can't connect to SQL SERVER 2000 (windows 2000 server) because of a new KB Upgrade Windows (security) on the Client side (windows seven PC)

Tags: ssl, sql-server-2000, sqlexception

I have a new error because of a new KB upgrade windows security! This worked very well yet before...
I don't understand why.... Have you an idea please or advice to search?
( i 'm not sure but it seems its because of KB3175024 or KB 3185319....)

> > > ERROR:
> > >       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was established with the server, but then an error occurred during prior negotiations with the logon. (Provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - At least one of the parameters passed to the function was invalid.)
> >
> > SOURCE CODE C#
> >     try
> >                 {
> >                     string connectionString = "workstation id=STAR17;packet size=4096;user id=sa;Password=******;data source=STAR17;persist securit" +
> >                         "y info=False;initial catalog=REFERENTIEL";

```
            myConnection_REF = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            myConnection_REF.Open();
            REF_Connected = true;
            Console.WriteLine("REFERENTIEL Connection status: " + myConnection_REF.State);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("REFERENTIEL Connection error: Connection is already open");
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("REFERENTIEL Connection error: " + e.ToString());
        }
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 3175024, we were getting a SSL error when connecting to Citrix and as soon as we removed this update we could connect to Citrix again.  Unfortunately if you are set to get updates automatically it will come back as Microsoft categorized this one as critical or security.  Like you we were connecting to an old version of the software, the newer versions were not having a problem.